# how to stop recursion and/or restart the current function with updated variables

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've got two arrays which are updating themselves and each other based on criteria (it is way longer to describe than I suspect the solution is).

What I end up with is a function which calls itself within a while loop. As you can imagine, this causes a ridiculous amount of recursion.

Here's an example (keeping it short)

```
var buildArray=firstFunction(new Array(), existingArray)

function firstFunction(thisArray, existingArray){
     for(test1=0; test1<existingArray.length; test1++){
         if(existingArray[test1][3]=='2'){
           secondFunction(thisArray, existingArray, test1);
        }
     }

function secondFunction(thisArray, existingArray, t1){
       for(test2=0; test2<thisArray.length; test2++){
          if(thisArray[test1]<=existingArray[test2][1] || thisArray[test1]>existingArray[test2[0]){
            // do a bunch of stuff to existingArray, now that existingArray has changed, the whole process needs to start again FROM THE BEGINNING!!!
     return firstFunction(new Array(), existingArray);

              // check that the value isn't already in the 'thisArray'
   var check= new Array(existingArray[test1]);
  else if (jQuery.inArray(check, thisArray==-1){
         // value isn't in the new array, so add it
        thisArray.push(check);
       // thisArray has changed. need to restart the the second function
       secondFunction(thisArray,existingArray);
     }

   }
 }

}
}
```

I was hoping that

```
return secondFunction(thisArray, existingArray);
```

would reset and restart the function, but apparently that isn't happening.

Is there a way to stop the current function and loops and restart with the updated variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i do not get what you are trying yo do, however based on the fact that return stop the execution in the secondFunction, and thisArray is never changed, 
you can add a loop to the firstFunction:

```
function firstFunction(thisArray, existingArray){
    var restart = true;
    while(restart)
    {
        restart = false;
         for(test1=0; !restart && test1<existingArray.length; test1++){
             if(existingArray[test1][3]=='2'){
               if(secondFunction(thisArray, existingArray, test1))
               {
                restart = true;
               }
            }
         }
    }
```

and in the secondFunction instead of returning the array return true:

```
  if(thisArray[test1]<=existingArray[test2][1] || thisArray[test1]>existingArray[test2[0]){
    // do a bunch of stuff to existingArray, now that existingArray has changed, the whole process needs to start again FROM THE BEGINNING!!!
 return true;
```

Comment: Thanks Scrum Meister. To get into the guts of what I'm doing is quite confusing. I didn't want to cloud the problem with a bunch of stuff not relevant to the bit I was having difficulty with. This question is the starting pointhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485262/javascript-conflicting-times-in-array, and from there I decided that if I sorted all the times in one array, then looked for conflicts, adjusted to the conflicts and tracked which time was unavailable in a separate array, I could go through them recursively and make adjustments. I'm not sure if your solution is working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I noticed:

- in `secondFunction()` you access `test1` even though you have a parameter `t1`
- the second call to `secondFunction()` doesn't contain that last parameter
- the second call to `secondFunction()` doesn't have a return before it even though you mentioned it in your OP
- there's a line `else if (jQuery.inArray(check, thisArray==-1){`, which is missing a ")"
- there's a line `if(thisArray[test1]<=existingArray[test2][1] || thisArray[test1]>existingArray[test2[0]){` missing a "]"
- in `for(test1=0; test1<existingArray.length; test1++){` it should be `for(var test1...` to let the parser know it's a variable on its own in the recursion (assuming you want this to happen of course)
- in `for(test2=0; test2<thisArray.length; test2++){` it should be `for(var test2...` to let the parser know it's a variable on its own in the recursion (assuming you want this to happen of course)
- ...

I'm saying that you edited the code to post it here. That is fine of course, but it makes me believe that some part of the code is missing.

As far as the missing `var`s is concerned, that may be in your interest, but the parser may get confused. If there's no `var` the variable is defined at document-level, not at function-level nor at the innermost scope. I don't know if you aware of this or if it's an issue.

Comment: Sorry about the errors in the post sjngm, I was retyping from one computer which had the code onto another where I've got stack. I did mention in the post that i had shortened the code so that there wasn't confusion with all the other stuff going on. I knew what the problem was, just not the solution. I'll be more careful with my retyping in the future and will test the code before posting.